# how to add Array index value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

first, I create empty Array(Kotlin) instance in companion object.

```
 companion object {
        var strarray: Array<String> = arrayOf()
        var objectarray: LinkedHashMap<Int, List<Any>> = LinkedHashMap<Int, List<Any>>()
    }
```

and I expected that I use empty array instance when read textString from CSV File.

```
 fun csvFileToString():String {

    val inputStream = File(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
            .plus("/src/main/SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv")).inputStream()
    val reader = inputStream.bufferedReader()
    var iterator = reader.lineSequence().iterator()
    var index:Int = 1;

    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        var lineText:String = iterator.next()
       strarray.set(index, lineText)
       index++
    }

    return ""
}
```

but when I run that source code

```
a.csvFileToString()
println(CsvParser.strarray)
```

occured exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 
strarray.set(index, lineText) <<<<<<<<< because of this line
```

can I use Array(from kotlin collection) like ArrayList(from java collection)?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a new item to an array using `+=`, for example: `item += item`

```
private var songs: Array<String> = arrayOf()
   fun add(input: String) {
        songs += input
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Size of `Array` is defined at its creation and cannot be modified - in your example it equals `0`.

If you want to create `Array` with dynamic size you should use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

- `arrayOf` gives you an array. Arrays have fixed length even in Java.
- `listOf` gives you an immutable list. You cannot add or remove items in this list.
- What you're looking for is `mutableListOf<String>`.

In your current approach, reusing a member property, don't forget to clear the list before every use.

Your code can be further simplified (and improved) like so:

```
out.clear()
inputStream.bufferedReader().use { reader -> // Use takes care of closing reader.
    val lines = reader.lineSequence()
    out.addAll(lines) // MutableList can add all from sequence.
}
```

Now imagine you wanted to consume the output list but needed to parse another file at the same time.

Consider working towards a *pure function* (no side effects, for now no accessing member properties) and simplifying it even further:

```
fun csvFileToString(): String { // Now method returns something useful.
    val inputStream = File(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
            .plus("/src/main/SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv")).inputStream()

    inputStream.bufferedReader().use {
        return it.lineSequence().joinToString("\n")
    }
}
```

In this case we can totally skip the lists and arrays and just read the text:

```
inputStream.bufferedReader().use {
    return it.readText()
}
```

I'm assuming that's what you wanted in the first place.

Kotlin has a lot of useful extension functions built-in. Look for them first.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a *pure function* as it does access external resources (csv file in this case)

Comment: @pwolaq I know, how to better describe it?